# Get path to folder using uigetfile in Matlab

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I know that you can create a file browser in Matlab using uigetfile. However, I want the user to be able to select a destination folder. I am currently using the following code:

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile;
```

Using this, the user has to select a file within the destination folder in order to actually be able to close the file browser. Is there a better way of doing this ? For example, allow the user to select a folder and this closes the file browser whilst returning just the path to the chosen folder. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[UIGETDIR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uigetdir.html) is what you're looking for.